# Expected value, pairwise incompatibility and independency of events

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence

$A, B, C$ are three probability events, with probability $1/2, 1/3, 1/6$ respectively.

**a)** Indicating with X the number of how many of these events will occur, compute E(X).

**b)** What is the probability that at least one of them will occur $(X\geqslant{1})$ if the three events are pairwise incompatible?

**c)** What is the probability that at least one of them will occur $(X\geqslant{1})$ if the three events are completely independent?

My attempt:

**a)** $X=[0,1,2,3]$ so $E[X] = 0*p(0) + 1*p(1) + 2*p(2) + 3*p(3)$

= 0*P({None of the events occurs}) + 1*P({Just 1 event occur}) + 2*P({Just 2 events occurs}) + 3*P({All the events occurs})

= 0*$P({\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}\cap\bar{C}}) + 1*P({(A\cap\overline{{B\cup{C}}}})\cup({B\cap\overline{{A\cup{C}}}})\cup({C\cap\overline{{A\cup{B}}}})) + 2*P(({(A\cap{B})\cap\bar{C}})\cup({(A\cap{C})\cap\bar{B}})\cup({(B\cap{C})\cap\bar{A}})) + 3*P(A\cap{B}\cap{C})$

Now, using De Morgan $(\overline{{X\cup{Y}}}=\bar{X}\cap\bar{Y})$ to simplify the second and third addend:

= 0*$P({\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}\cap\bar{C}}) + 1*P({(A\cap\bar{B}\cap\bar{C}})\cup(B\cap\bar{A}\cap\bar{C})\cup(C\cap\bar{A}\cap\bar{B})) + 2*P(({(A\cap{B})\cap\bar{C}})\cup({(A\cap{C})\cap\bar{B}})\cup({(B\cap{C})\cap\bar{A}})) + 3*P({A\cap{B}\cap{C}})$

These events are clearly pairwise disjoint, so:

= 0*$P(\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}\cap\bar{C}) + P(A\cap\bar{B}\cap\bar{C})+P(B\cap\bar{A}\cap\bar{C})+P(C\cap\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}) + 2*P(A\cap{B}\cap\bar{C})+2*P(A\cap{C}\cap\bar{B})+2*P(B\cap{C}\cap\bar{A}) + 3*P({A\cap{B}\cap{C}})$

How can I continue from here if I don't know if there is dependence or not in this latest events?

**b)** We know from hypothesis that $A\cap{B}=∅, A\cap{C}=∅, B\cap{C}=∅$ so I can say with confidence that the probability of the union of the events is the sum of the probabilities:

P({At least one event occur}) = $P(A\cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/6 = 1$

**c)** We know from hypothesis that $A∩B∩C=∅$ so I can say with confidence that $P(A∩B∩C)=P(A)*P(B)*P(C).$ It's easy to see that if A, B, C are mutually independent, the complements are independent.

P({At least one event occur}) = $P(A\cup{B}\cup{C})$ = 1 − P({None of the events will occur}) = 1 − $P({\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}\cap\bar{C}}) = 1-[(1-1/2)(1-1/3)(1-1/6)] = 13/18 = 0.72$

Is this correct?

Comment: The Math in part (a) may be drastically simplified.  See [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/), which includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not independent.

Comment: I don't know if I am getting this right @user2661923 but from the link you sent me I think that I can rethink the problem using the indicator variables because this is useful when the random variable under consideration is counting the number of occurrences of simple events and using the linearity of expectation. Is this what you were trying to say?

Comment: For what it's worth, I started to leave a comprehensive answer to the entire question, and then stopped and discarded my answer.  I find the problem's wording ambiguous.  For example, in part (b), since $(1/2) + (1/3) + (1/6)$ equals $1$ does this mean that you are always guaranteed that exactly one of the three events must occur.  To answer part (b), assuming that it is from a book or class, you would have to review previous problems that were part of your training that had similar wording.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then, you would have to reverse-engineer the problem composer's intent, based on the perceived problem composer's intent for similarly worded problems that were part of your training.  One other detail.  The **statistic** that at least one of the events occurs should be represented by $$X \geq 1$$ rather than $$X > 1.$$

Comment: To illustrate my confusion, one scenario is that you toss a (fair) 6-sided die one time, and the events $E_1, E_2, E_3$ refer to the die coming up [1,2,or 3], [4,5], or [6], respectively.  A different scenario is that you have three different batters that are about to bat in an inning, you are given that they will each bat exactly one time in the inning, and you are given that the probabilities of each one getting a hit are (1/2), (1/3), (1/6), respectively.  Then, in Part b, it would be as if you are also given that it is impossible for more than one of the three to get a hit.

Comment: Re last comment, in the second scenario, one immediate point of possible ambiguity is:  do the probabilities of (1/2), (1/3), (1/6) generally apply, or [in part b] only apply **after** the assumption that the events are pairwise incompatible?

Comment: Okay @user2661923 so for the first point (a) I think that I can use this: Let say that X is an arbitrary variable that counts how many of these events will occur and $\mathbb{1}_{A}$ the characteristic function of A, $\mathbb{1}_{B}$ the characteristic function of B and $\mathbb{1}_{C}$ the characteristic function of C. We even know that $E[\mathbb{1}_{X}]=P(X). So E[X]=E[\mathbb{1}_{A}+\mathbb{1}_{B}+\mathbb{1}_{C}]=E[\mathbb{1}_{A}]+E[\mathbb{1}_{B}]+E[\mathbb{1}_{C}]=P({A})+P({B})+P({C}).$ The problem is that I don't think this make a lot of sense, how can E[X]=1?

Comment: I think that in part (b) the probabilities only apply after adding the pairwise incompatible hypothesis, and I believe this is a hint to make us use the sigma-additive property.

Comment: I believe that between the two scenarios you posted (concerning the die and the other) the correct interpretation of the problem is the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is much simpler than initially assumed.

**a)** Let say that X is an arbitrary variable that counts how many of these events will occur and $\mathbb{1}_{A}$ the characteristic function of A, $\mathbb{1}_{B}$ the characteristic function of B and $\mathbb{1}_{C}$ the characteristic function of C. We even know that [$\mathbb{1}_{X}$]=P().

So $E[X] = E[\mathbb{1}_{A}+\mathbb{1}_{B}+\mathbb{1}_{C}] = E[\mathbb{1}_{A}]+E[\mathbb{1}_{B}]+E[\mathbb{1}_{C}]=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1.$

**b)** We know from hypothesis that $A\cap{B}=∅, A\cap{C}=∅, B\cap{C}=∅$ so I can say with confidence that the probability of the union of the events is the sum of the probabilities:

P({At least one event occur}) = $P(A\cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/6 = 1$

**c)** We know from hypothesis that $A∩B∩C=∅$ so I can say with confidence that $P(A∩B∩C)=P(A)*P(B)*P(C).$ It's easy to see that if A, B, C are mutually independent, the complements are independent.

P({At least one event occur}) = $P(A\cup{B}\cup{C})$ = 1 − P({None of the events will occur}) = 1 − $P({\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}\cap\bar{C}}) = 1-[(1-1/2)(1-1/3)(1-1/6)] = 13/18 = 0.72$

That's all? Could anyone confirm?